# set credentials: "include" in cy.request()

Tags: api, cypress

This works fine in dev console

```
fetch('https://api.my-url.com', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': document.cookie
    }
})
```

I tried to transfer it to Cypress like this

```
cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: "include", //this is the problem line
    url: 'https://api.my-url.com',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cookie': document.cookie
    }
})
```

but the RequestOptions are  'auth,
body,
encoding,
followRedirect,
form,
gzip,
headers,
method'
so I can not set credentials to 'include' like this.

When I try to send the request without the credentials option I got error
"The response we received from your web server was:  > 401: Unauthorized"

Are there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

If you look through [Cypress request and cookies](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-request-and-cookies/), the implication is that `cy.request()` *always* sends `credentials: 'include'`.

> How to use cy.request, window.fetch, and cy.task commands to make HTTP requests to the server with and without cookies.
>
> If you need to make an HTTP request without default cookies, use the window.fetch or the cy.task command.

That could be taken to be talking about *sending* cookies with the request, but [further down](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-request-and-cookies/#windowfetch-without-cookies) there is an example of using `credentials: 'omit'` to stop the server sending it's default cookie `mycookie=testcookie`

> **window.fetch without cookies**
>
> ```js
> it('fetch without page cookies', () => {
>   cy.wrap(fetch('/print-cookies', { credentials: 'omit' }))   
>     .then(r => r.json())
>     // no cookies were sent with the fetch request
>     .should('deep.equal', {})
> })
> ```

Contrast to the `cy.request()` example

```js
cy.request('/print-cookies')
  .its('body')
  .should('deep.equal', { mycookie: 'testcookie' })
```

and the conclusion I jump to is that `cy.request()` always uses `credentials: 'include'`.

Comment: thank you for your input! I forgot to add the error I got when sending it without credentials option, sorry for that. Also this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71483921/cypress-sets-credentials-omit-as-opposed-to-include-when-chrome-fires-api . I saw the question is not answered and OP moved away from Cypress. Sadly this is not an option for me

Comment: The error means you have not provided the right credentials, so `document.cookie` is suspect. `credentials: 'include'` just means you are allowed to send and receive cookies cross-domain.